# Unable to change the background color using vuetify theme?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

Here, I have been working vuetify theme to change the background color of the app and nav bar using a pop up form to choose the color for the app and nav bar but due to the some reason my color buttons  are  not able to change the background color for the app and nav bar. I am using vuetify color and theme to change the background color.

```
<template>
<nav>


        <v-app-bar  color="primary darken-3"
                   height="45px"
                   clipped
                   dark app>
            <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click.stop="drawer = ! drawer">

            </v-app-bar-nav-icon>

            <v-spacer> </v-spacer>

            <v-btn text icon>
                <v-icon style="">mdi-star</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
            <v-menu offset-y origin="center center" class="elevation-1" :nudge-bottom="14" transition="scale-transition" max-width="10">
                <v-btn icon text slot="activator">
                    <v-badge color="red" overlap>
                        <span slot="badge">3</span>
                        <v-icon medium>mdi-bell</v-icon>
                    </v-badge>
                </v-btn>
                <notification-list></notification-list>
            </v-menu>

                <v-menu
                        bottom
                        offset-y
                        :nudge-bottom="10"
                >
                    <template  v-slot:activator="{ on }">

                        <v-btn
                                dark
                                icon
                                v-on="on"
                        >

                            <span><v-icon>mdi-account-circle-outline</v-icon></span>

                        </v-btn>

                    </template>

                <v-list   flat>

                    <v-list-item active-class="border">
                        <v-list-item-icon style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px" >
                            <v-icon>mdi-account-circle-outline</v-icon>
                        </v-list-item-icon>
                        <v-list-item-title>Profile</v-list-item-title>
                    </v-list-item>

                    <v-list-item class="ml-1" active-class="border">
                        <v-list-item-icon>
                            <v-icon >mdi-logout-variant</v-icon>
                        </v-list-item-icon>
                        <v-list-item-title>logout</v-list-item-title>
                    </v-list-item>



                      <v-list-item  @click.stop="dialog = true">
                     <v-list-item-icon >  
                         <v-icon>mdi-select-color</v-icon>
                         </v-list-item-icon>
                            <v-list-item-title>Theme</v-list-item-title>

                            <v-dialog
      v-model="dialog"
      max-width="290"
    >

        <v-card>
        <v-card-title>Theme</v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>
          <v-btn
              v-for="item in colors"
              :key="item"
              :color="item"
                       @click="changeTheme(item)"

              class="ma-2"
            >

                     <template v-if="theme != item" v-slot:default>

              <span class="text-truncate" style="width:120px;">
        {{item.replace(/-/g, '')}}
      </span>
       </template>
        </v-btn>



              </v-card-text>
   <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="dialog = false">Close</v-btn>
          <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="dialog = false">Save</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>




      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>

                    </v-list-item>


                </v-list>
            </v-menu>
        </v-app-bar>


        <v-navigation-drawer @click="!drawer"
                             dark
                             app
                             stateless
                             border
                             color="primary darken-1"
                             value="true"
                             :mini-variant="drawer">
            <v-layout  column align-center>
                <v-flex class="ma-2">
                    <v-avatar>
                         <v-img width="80" :src="require('../../../images/chillibiz.png')"> </v-img>
                    </v-avatar>
                    <p v-if="!drawer" class="white--text subheading mt-1 text-center" style="font-size:0.9em">ChilliBiz</p>
                </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
            <v-divider class=" mt-0 mb-0" />
            <v-list nav
                    dense
                    class="py-0" >
                <v-list-item v-for="item in menus" :key="item.name" :to="item.url" >
                    <v-list-item-icon>
                        <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
                    </v-list-item-icon>
                    <v-list-item-content>
                        <v-list-item-title v-if="item.url=='/'">{{ item.name }}</v-list-item-title>
                        <v-list-item-title  v-if="item.url=='/hr'">{{ item.name }}<hrm/></v-list-item-title>
                        <v-list-item-title  v-if="item.url=='/inventory'">{{ item.name }}<master/></v-list-item-title>
                        <v-list-item-title  v-if="item.url=='/finace&accounts'">{{ item.name }}<finance/></v-list-item-title>
                        <v-list-item-title  v-if="item.url=='/reports'">{{ item.name }}</v-list-item-title>
                        <v-list-item-title  v-if="item.url=='/system'">{{ item.name }}</v-list-item-title>  
                    </v-list-item-content>
                </v-list-item>
            </v-list>
        </v-navigation-drawer>
    </nav>


</template>
<script>
    import hrm from "./HRcomponent"
    import master from "./MasterComponent"
    import finance from "./FinanceComponent"

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                 drawer:false,
                   dialog: false,
                 searchOpen: false,
                menus: [
                    {icon:'',name:'', url:''}
                ],
                theme: '',
                colors: ["red","pink","purple","deep-purple","indigo","blue","light-blue","cyan","teal","green","light-green","lime","yellow","amber","orange","deep-orange","brown","blue-grey","grey", "black"],
            }
        },
        methods: {
  changeTheme (item) {
    this.theme = item
    this.$vuetify.theme.themes.dark.primary = this.theme
  }
},
        created() {
            axios
                .get('api/menuslevel0')
                .then(response => (this.menus = response.data))
        },     
        components :{
            hrm,
            master,
            finance
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.theme` is set to string color: 'red' for example

so this line of code is trying to set sting as vuetify color

```
this.$vuetify.theme.themes.dark.primary = this.theme
```

and this is not valid

**you need to convert it to hexbefore appending it**

you may use vuetify color picker to set color instead of adding static colors

you can check [this demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-playground-3lyl6)

### update

if you still want to add static color you can update your `color` array and make it array of object as:

```
text: /* name of color */,
value: /* color value in HEX format */
```

then you can render your color text, and when click, aplply its value

check [this demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-playground-o9wwk)

Comment: I was assigned to use adding static colors....Can't it be possible to change the color by adding static colors?

Comment: yes, you can convert your static array to array of object: `{text: color-text, value: /*color value in hex*/}`

Comment: Okeyy... I will wait for your demo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213769/discussion-between-kareem-dabbeet-and-kinley-om).